# Returning all elements of a jsonb scalar in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb column  that has scalar values. I am trying to return all elements of that scalar value as individual rows. My postgres version is 9.6. For example:

```
SELECT jsonb ->> 2
FROM (
    SELECT '["mango", "aaple", "banana", "orange", "berry"]'::jsonb
) s
```

The above sql returns `banana` as expected as it is the 2nd item(`jsonb ->>2`) within the scalar value. How do I return all items as individual rows like the following?

```
mango
aaple
banana
orange
berry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the function jsonb_array_elements  :

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(jsonb)::text
FROM (
SELECT '["mango", "aaple", "banana", "orange", "berry"]'::jsonb
) s


result: 
"mango"
"aaple"
"banana"
"orange"
"berry"
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. How do you return `mango aaple` etc. as opposed to `"mango" "aaple"`?

Comment: I figured it our `jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb)`. Thank you.